# How to do a recursive JSON based on variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion, postman

I work in a Postman and write code in javascript. I have a global variable called path which simply is a path e.g. Device/XYZ/conf_1

My code which makes an array from a string:

```
var path = globals.path.split("/");
var len = path.length;
```

Now I want to make a recursive JSON which be used in body request
In this specific case there should be JSON like this:

```
var jsonPath = JSON.stringify([{
    "name": path[0],
    "type": "Group",
    "children": [{
        "name": path[1],
        "type": "Group",
        "children": [{
            "name": path[2],
            "type": "Group",
            "children": []
        }]
    }]
}]);
pm.globals.set('jsonPath', jsonPath);
```

Every index of a path is an object with parameters called name,type and children (type is the same of everyone). Moreover, every index should be a child of previous index and their value should be placed in "name". Of course its must be a recursive function which automatically makes a JSON.

Thanks for any kind of help. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```js
var path = 'hello/1/2/3';

var paths = path.split('/');

var resultObj = paths.reduce((resultObj, content, index) => {
    var traverse = resultObj ;
    for (var i=0; i<index; i++) {
        traverse = traverse[0]['children'];
    }
    var obj = {
        name: content,
        type: 'group',
    };
    obj['children'] = [];
    traverse.push(obj);
    return resultObj;
}, []);

console.log(resultObj);
```